# How to trigger an android app on the phone using the laptop?

Tags: android

I have an application on my G1 Android Dev phone(android 1.5). I need to trigger this application automatically from my laptop. The system will not be deployed in an area where there is WiFi, so I cannot send a packet to a service on the phone which will be listening for a particular packet from the laptop and then call an intent to launch my application. Is there any way in which I can send out a packet using the USB cable to a service running on the phone? Are there APIs available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to invoke the launch app intent via [adb shell](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands), the start command, and the application's launch intent.  It looks like [this person](http://www.lysesoft.com/support/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=197#p600) got it to work.  This may require rooting a physical device.

**Edit:**
Another idea: launch the app with the [UI Excerciser monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html), but specify 0 for the event count.

Comment: What I ideally want to accomplish is to send out data, maybe in the format of a string to a service running on the phone using the USB cable. Is that possible?

Comment: Both of the above ideas address the solution.  The data would be in the form of an Intent, which can contain string and other data.  In you're app, you'll want you're app to respond to that intent in the IntentFilter of your Activity, Service, or BroadcastReceiver